# How do I drag an object that is not filled by the centre in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I have a simple unfilled circle shape:

[image]

I want to drag it and have it snap to the grid by the centre point. The problem is I can't grab it by the centre with the mouse. If I move the mouse away from the lines of the circle, the pointer changes from the drag cursor to the normal one.

Therefore I can only make it snap to the sides or nodes.

I know I could add some lines to the group and use those to drag by, but assuming I don't want to add extra fluff to the drawing how can I drag this so that it snaps to the centre?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have an object selected, holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> then dragging anywhere on the canvas lets you move the selected object - even from far away outside its bounding-box.

[image: Demonstration of alt-dragging]

Note that in some Linux environments, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-dragging is bound to moving the whole window on the OS-level, so you might need to disable or rebind it in your OS settings, to access this feature inside Inkscape.

You can also rebind this inside Inkscape in the preferences under 'Interface → Keyboard' inside the 'Modifiers' tab under 'Selection → Forced Drag'.

[image: Preferences open with relevant setting highlighted.]

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn I tried alt but it definitely works.